# Trying to get an Object from a List in Java

Tags: java

I'm familiar with getting an object from an `ArrayList` thru their index and placing the data in a variable but I seem to be having difficulty with this one.

Okay here's an update to be more specific (and to remove redundancy in the code).

The query returns a list of numbers. I'm supposed to get the one at `index[0]`. The value at `index[0]` is the number **20**.
The query I made successfully returns a list with the expected values.

Now the code I made is this:

```
List noByDivision = dao.getNumber(division);
Number noOfRoutes = (Number)noByDivision.get(0);
```

The second line does not place the data from `(Number)noByDivision.get(0);` to `noOfRoutes`. Can anyone suggest how to get that data?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: and are you really getting back a list of lists from the dao?

Comment: You are not giving much information here. 1. What is the error. 2. We are made to assume that the list retrieved from the database contains another list (we assume the cast worked). Is it possible the list `listFromQuery` is empty and is throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Instead of casting what your methods return, why don't you specify the TYPE of the lists?

Comment: @kostja In the webapp, nothing happens and in debug when I execute the third line for some reason it jumps to "AstValue.class". :/

Comment: @PaulW Yes, it returns the expected list from the dao. :)

Comment: @JohnB listFromQuery isn't empty. :(

Comment: You are using raw types here which is discouraged. I think if you start using generics here the problem will be obvious. And by the way you should share the knowledge about the exception which is thrown at line 3.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code this way:

```
try{
    List<List<Number>> getFromDatabase = dao.getBoxes();
    List<Number> listFromQuery = getFromDatabase.get(0);
    Number noOfBoxes = listFromQuery.get(0);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage())
}
```

and check for some kind of runtime exception in your piece of code.

If no exception is thrown, maybe `noOfBoxes` is simply `null`.

Comment: Weird, it says "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"

Comment: @Nicole So it seems to be a `String` not a `Number` :) You need to parse it using, for instance, `Integer.getInteger(noOfBoxes)` or some other numeric type...